# JS Delay Script Not Using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delayed-execution

This is a follow up question. I have script that I though would work. This script delays my script from running similar to setTimeout. I can't use setTimeout as my software/platform doesn't allow it. So i am looking for a workaround.

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
        break;
    }
}
}
```

This function delays the script but it also delays all background scripts from running as well. Im trying to delay my script from running so that all background scripts can finish running. The fact that the above stops all scripts from running defeats the purpose and does not alter to execution order.

I need a script that will delay a block of script without delaying all other background scripts so that they can finish running. Please note that my software/platform does not allow setTimeout and that is why I am looking for a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: JS in the browser is single threaded. You must use the event loop to accomplish what you want. AFAIK the only way to queue a function to be run after a time period is to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Comment: "*my software/platform doesn't allow it*" - what is your software/platform, and how does it manage delays? Does it support asynchrony? What are "background scripts"? This is all vital information needed to answer your question.